# The wave equation in action

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics

The vibration of a piano string is governed by the wave equation $u_{tt} - c^2u_{xx} = 0$ where $c$ is related to the tension and the mass density. Suppose a string is hit by a hammer on the interval $(-a,a) \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $a > 0$. A flea sits at a point $l>0$ where $l>a$. How long does it take for the disturbance to reach the flea?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Keyword: *finite speed of propagation*.